# Django queryset foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, django-queryset

What is the proper way to do reverse lookups in Django for foreign key relationships?  For instance suppose i have the following 2 models.

```
class Songs(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    genre = models.ForeignKey('Genres')

class Genres(models.Model):
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

If I wanted users to be able to search songs based on genre how would i do that?

For example the below is what i want to do, but i know it doesn't work because the genre column of the Songs table is an ID, not a keyword.

```
song = models.Songs.objects.get(genre='Jazz')
```

Comment: You should try to name your model classes in the singular.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the [*double underscore syntax*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups) to reach the `genre` field in the related model:

```
Songs.objects.filter(genre__genre='Jazz')
```

---

For the readability purposes and consistency, consider renaming the `genre` field to `name`:

```
class Genres(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```